# How to know the current state of UIPageViewController in its parent UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` and inside which I am instantiating a `UIPageViewController`.

Is there a way i can find out which page the user has navigated on the parent `UIViewController`?

Example: Say on the below image; each time the user slides in `UIPageViewController` i want to show the slide number on the SLIDE NUMBER:X place.

I can achieve this using notification but wanted to know if there are better ways to do this?

[image]

Here is some sample code i am using right now:
In my XYZViewController Class

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        generateArrayOfViews()  //This would generate a array of view controllers to display within UIPageViewController


        let pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("pageViewController") as! UIPageViewController

        let firstController = arrayOfViewControllers[locations.count - 1]
        let startingViewControllers: Array = [firstController]

        pageViewController.dataSource = self

        pageViewController.setViewControllers(startingViewControllers, direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

        pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 139, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)


        self.addChildViewController(pageViewController)
        self.view.insertSubview(pageViewController.view, atIndex: 1)
        pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }
```

Also have the following methods implemented>

```
presentationCountForPageViewController and 
presentationIndexForPageViewController
```

Trying to know what i should implement on XYZViewController to know the selected view controller inside the pageViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass index of the visible page as follows:

```
ContentViewController *viewController = [self.pageViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
currentIndex = [modelArray indexOfObject:[viewController page]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a NSArray with identifiers like this :

```
self.pageIdentifiers = @[@"first",@"second"];
```

Each ViewController I'll instantiate, will have a a pageIdentifier attribute set, depending on its position in the PageViewController.

Then I could know the index of the ViewController by implementing this method :

```
- (NSUInteger)indexOfViewController:(ViewController *)viewController {
      // Return the index of the given view controller.
      return [self.pageIdentifiers indexOfObject:viewController.pageIdentifier];
}
```

I also could trigger an UI event in the implementation of these methods :

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```